# How to call user defined jquery or ajax function calls in Jqtouch

Tags: jqtouch

I am trying to add some functionality in a wordpress theme based on JQtouch. I want to run an ajax call to replace the content of a div. But the jQtouch not allowing me to run the code. It runs its default event.

i Have used this code to bind the function, where listArticles() will call my Ajax request.

```
$(function(){
$('a[href="#articles"]').bind('click', listArticles());             
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is wrong, it should either point to the function or be an anonymous function itself.

```
$(function(){
  $('a[href="#articles"]').bind('click', listArticles);             
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
  $('a[href="#articles"]').bind('click', function() { listArticles() });             
});
```